# Android : store ParseObject data when app goes to background

Tags: android, parse-platform

In my code I have this.

```
public static List<MeetingApp> meetingAppList;
```

MeetingApp is a kind of ParseObject and the code is part of a Fragment.
The problem I have is when my app goes to background it seems like the data is destroyed. When I start the app again it crashes because the list is missing and the fragment needs the data. The fragment is part of a ViewPager and setRetainInstance(true) apparently doesn't work;

I tried to save the object but ParseObject isn't Parcelable or Serializable.

Any idea of how I can store the data or save the state of fragment and then restore it?.  Is it possible to keep it in JSON?.

Regards.

Edit 1: This is the traceback of the crash if I keep the data in a Json format.

```
Process: mcongress.mobicongress.com.mcongressapp, PID: 3922
java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeYearAndDay(GregorianCalendar.java:798)
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.fullFieldsCalc(GregorianCalendar.java:480)
        at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(GregorianCalendar.java:573)
        at java.util.Calendar.complete(Calendar.java:830)
        at java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1195)
        at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1183)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.formatImpl(SimpleDateFormat.java:518)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:818)
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:307)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.write(DateTypeAdapter.java:90)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.DateTypeAdapter.write(DateTypeAdapter.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:89)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:195)
```

Now i'm trying to keep the list in the ParseLocalDatastore with a pin name. I think that could be an easy solution.

Comment: You could have a look on the gson lib to serialize it to a json and deserializ it again.

Comment: Are you cleaning up any of those objects in `onPause`, by chance?  Please show us the traceback of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

So just parse it to a Json using the gson library

**(Serialization)**

```
List<MeetingApp> meetingAppList;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(meetingAppList);  
//==> json is [{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"},...
```

Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.

**(Deserialization)**

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YourClass>>() {
                }.getType();
List<MeetingApp> meetingAppList = gson.fromJson(json, listType);   
//==> obj2 is just like obj
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems the object has a circular reference, because the java.lang.StackOverflowError appeared. I'm going to check out that.

Comment: have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

Parse has the function to save Objects inside a local database. It helps you save data offline, but can also be used for storing data for your app!

Havea look at this link about the [Parse Local Datastore](http://blog.parse.com/2014/04/30/take-your-app-offline-with-parse-local-datastore/)